# $Y \sim Pois(\mu)$ random variable with $\mu > 0$ Prove that $Y$ is even

Tags: probability, probability-theory, probability-distributions, poisson-distribution

Given $Y \sim Pois(\mu)$  a random variable  with mean $\mu > 0$.

$\Rightarrow \ P(Y=y) = e^{-\mu} \  \dfrac{\mu^{-y}}{y!}$

**Prove that $Y$ is even?**

I started my proof like this

$Y$ or $Y_n$ could be the number of phone calls received in a Mumbai call center with a mean of $\mu$ per hour. Let $n$ be the number of hours. 
Then $Y_{n-1}$ will be the number of calls among the first $n-1$ hours.

In $n-1$ hours we either have an even or an odd number of calls.  Then in the $n\text{th}$ hour, we may get either have even or odd number of calls.

If we have an even number of calls among the first $n-1$ hours, then we need to get an even number in the $n\text{th}$ hour to have an even total.

On the other hand, if we have an odd number among the first $n-1$ hours, we need odd number of calls received in the last hour. To have an even total number of calls throughout our $n$ hours.

So my probabilities should look something like:

$P(Y_n\ \text{even}) = P(Y_{n-1}\ \text{odd}) P(\text{hour n has odd calls}) + P(Y_{n-1}\ \text{even}) P(\text{hour n has odd calls})$

Is this analysis correct? If so how do I proceed please?

Thank you

Comment: Hint: you want $e^{-\mu}\sum \mu^k/k!$ where the sum ranges only over even values of $k$.  If you compare the sum for *all* $k$, with the same sum but with $\mu$ replaced by $-\mu$, the even terms are the same but the odd terms have different signs.  So add the two sums together and the odd terms will all cancel out.

Comment: "Prove that Y is even?" What does that mean? Y is random, even or odd, possibly odd.

Answer (score 0):

Are you trying to compute the probability of an even result?

If so, this is how you can do it:
$$ P(Y=``even")=\sum_{n=0}^\infty P(Y=2n)=\frac{1}{2}\left(\sum_{n=0}^\infty P(Y=n)+\sum_{n=0}^\infty (-1)^n P(Y=n)\right). $$

The last step is correct because we counted both the even probabilities twice and the odd probabilities are canceled out. Now you can proceed to inserting the PMF and computing the sums. The final result should be:
$$ P(Y=``even")=\frac{1}{2}\left(1+e^{-2\mu}\right). $$

Comment: I am trying to prove that Y is even.

Comment: That makes no sense. Y is a random variable that can have even or odd values.